# Flutter Firebase dont sign-out, after navigation to another page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

so I have this Flutter app navigable by a Drawer, Auth services are provided by Firebase.
Im currently working on flutter 2.5.1.

So when I login, the app takes me to the Main page that I set , it allows me to click logout ( before I navigate to another screen).
But when I navigate to another screen, and then click my logout button , it doesnt sign-out (visually) , and functions like get data from the user thats logged in, still works, returning data from the user.

[image: It gives me this line when i press the sign-out button D/FirebaseAuth( 5447): Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event. D/FirebaseAuth( 5447): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event.]

When that happens I have to hot reload and at that moment the app takes me back to the Login screen.

This is my sign-out function.

```
 Future cerrarSesion() {
   return FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
 }
```

This is my Main File

```
return FutureBuilder(
    future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      return StreamProvider<User>.value(
        initialData: null,
        value: AuthService().usuario,
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: regularFont,
              primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
              elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: kPrimaryColor)),
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: kBackgroundColor),
          home: BasePage(),
        ),
      );
    });
```

This is the method of BasePage(), (the one that evaluate if the user is logged in )

```
 final usuario = Provider.of<User>(context);
return usuario == null ? LoginPage() : MyProfilePage();
```

I've tried with and without null-safety, changing flutter version and still doesnt work.

I appreciate guidance on this case, because I dont have idea what could it be the cause of this problem.

Comment: what is `final usuario = Provider.of<User>(context);` returning?

Comment: @PeterHaddad
I think thats working fine, bc when I login it returns all attributes from the object User,
and when i sign-out it returns null